# How to join two different line plots on a single axis so that they look smooth?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I'm trying to create the following 3 line charts on a single axis using matplotlib. The red chart ending value is where the yellow chart values start. I want to remove the extending flat line of red plot at the end so that it connects with the yellow chart smoothly.

```
ax.plot(index, red.interpolate(method='time'), color=colors, linewidth=2, label=label, alpha=0.8)
ax.plot(index, yellow.interpolate(method='time'), color=colors, linewidth=2, label=label, alpha=0.8)
```

Following are my last 30 entries from the dataframe to get an idea of how the data looks like.

```
Index       Red    Yellow
2019-07-31  NaN     NaN
2019-08-31  NaN     NaN
2019-09-30  1.83    NaN
2019-10-31  NaN     NaN
2019-11-30  NaN     NaN
2019-12-31  1.07    NaN
2020-01-31  NaN     NaN
2020-02-29  NaN     NaN
2020-03-31  -4.75   NaN
2020-04-30  NaN     NaN
2020-05-31  NaN     NaN
2020-06-30  -24.01  NaN
2020-07-31  NaN     NaN
2020-08-31  NaN     NaN
2020-09-30  25.44   NaN
2020-10-31  NaN     NaN
2020-11-30  NaN     NaN
2020-12-31  1.70    1.70
2021-01-31  NaN     NaN
2021-02-28  NaN     NaN
2021-03-31  NaN     2.00
2021-04-30  NaN     NaN
2021-05-31  NaN     NaN
2021-06-30  NaN     4.15
2021-07-31  NaN     NaN
2021-08-31  NaN     NaN
2021-09-30  NaN     5.30
2021-10-31  NaN     NaN
2021-11-30  NaN     NaN
2021-12-31  NaN     4.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the interpolation method is filling in values after the last valid datapoint. Try the argument `limit_area="inside"` in the interpolation function.